# Tips to make plot with 5 datasets clear

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I'm really new to R and I'm trying to plot data from air polution with NOx from 5 different locations (having a data of monthly averages from every location from 01-1996 to 12-2019). Each plot line should represent different location.

I've created a ggplot but I find it really unclear. I would like to ask you about your tips to make that plot better to read (It will be no bigger than A4, because it will be included in my work and printed). I would also like to have more years on X axis (1996, 1997, 1998)

```
ALIBA <- read_csv("ALIBA_Praha/NOx/all_sorted.csv")
BMISA <- read_csv("BMISA_Mikulov/NOx/all_sorted.csv")
CCBDA <- read_csv("CCBDA_CB/NOx/all_sorted.csv")
TKARA <- read_csv("TKARA_Karvina/NOx/all_sorted.csv")
UULKA <- read_csv("UULKA_UnL/NOx/all_sorted.csv")


ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = ALIBA, aes(x = START_TIME, y = VALUE), color = "blue") +
  geom_line(data = BMISA, aes(x = START_TIME, y = VALUE), color = "red") +
  geom_line(data = CCBDA, aes(x = START_TIME, y = VALUE), color = "yellow") +
  geom_line(data = TKARA, aes(x = START_TIME, y = VALUE), color = "green") +
  geom_line(data = UULKA, aes(x = START_TIME, y = VALUE), color = "pink")
```

all csv files are in format:

```
     START_TIME,VALUE
    1996-01-01T00:00:00Z,61.3049451304964
    1996-02-01T00:00:00Z,47.7234010245664
    1996-03-01T00:00:00Z,33.083512309072
    1996-04-01T00:00:00Z,47.771166691758
    1996-05-01T00:00:00Z,24.7022422574005
    1996-06-01T00:00:00Z,25.4495954480684
    1996-07-01T00:00:00Z,23.301224242488
...
```

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, I would paste all data sets together:

```
ALIBA <- read_csv("ALIBA_Praha/NOx/all_sorted.csv")
ALIBA$Location <- "ALIBA" # and so on
BMISA <- read_csv("BMISA_Mikulov/NOx/all_sorted.csv")
CCBDA <- read_csv("CCBDA_CB/NOx/all_sorted.csv")
TKARA <- read_csv("TKARA_Karvina/NOx/all_sorted.csv")
UULKA <- read_csv("UULKA_UnL/NOx/all_sorted.csv")

df <- rbind(ALIBA, BMISA, ...) # and so on


ggplot(data = df, aes(x = START_TIME, y = VALUE, color = Location) +
  geom_line(size = 1) + # play with the stroke thickness
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set1") + # here you can choose from a wide variety of palettes, just google
```

How would you like to add more years? In the same graph (everything will be tiny) or in seperate "windows" (= facets, better)?